# Entropy of Gaussian mixture when variance of one component gets larger

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, entropy, mixture-distribution

I want to **prove or disprove** the following relation of differential entropies:

> **Conjecture**: $\displaystyle h(f) \le h(g)$

where $f, g$ the density functions of Gaussian mixture models with equal weights:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f \sim \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N} \left(-\mu, \sigma_0^2 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N} \left(\mu, \sigma_0^2 \right) \\
g \sim \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N} \left(-\mu, \sigma_0^2 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N} \left(\mu, \color{red}{\sigma_1^2} \right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

where the only difference is given by the variance of the second component of $g$, where $\sigma_0^2 \le \sigma_1^2$. The following is an example case when $\mu=1, \sigma_0=0.5, \sigma_1=1$.
[image]

This question is a special case of a [statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442001/relation-between-the-entropies-h-sum-w-i-f-i-h-sum-w-i-g-i-when-hf-i) that is generally not true (as disproved by @leonbloy).

---

### Try

Let $\displaystyle f = \frac{1}{2}f_0 + \frac{1}{2}f_1, g = \frac{1}{2}g_0 + \frac{1}{2}g_1$, with $f_0, f_1, g_0, g_1$ corresponding to each term.

$$
\begin{aligned}
h\left(f\right) -  h\left(g\right) &= - \int f \log f dx + \int \left( f+ g^\ast\right) \log \left( f+ g^\ast \right) dx \\
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\displaystyle g^\ast = g-f = \frac{1}{2} g_1 - \frac{1}{2} f_1$ from $f_0=g_0$. Here, I think I cannot proceed. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

---

Additionally, I tried to apply the following properties:

- $\displaystyle h\left(\mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\log \left(2\pi e \sigma^2\right)$, a strictly increasing function of $\sigma$: thus, $h\left(\mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma_0^2\right) \right) \le h\left(\mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma_1^2\right) \right)$
- By convolving $f$ by $\mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_1^2-\sigma_0^2\right)$, we can show $\displaystyle h(f) \le h\left( \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N} \left(-\mu, \sigma_1^2 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N} \left(\mu, \sigma_1^2 \right)\right)$